# False error in XAML parsing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

I'm getting a persistent non-fatal error when the building my WinRT project
Error 1 Closing tag for element '' was not found.

Of course there is an ending tag in my XAML and the project builds and runs just fine. How can I get VS to just give up on this error?

(Yes, I've tried a clean build)

Comment: Does it still happen after restarting VS?

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar error. Closing and reopening the solution resolved it. I believe this issue was fixed with Visual Studio 2012 Update 2

Have a look at : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dea9687f-5939-4a15-b197-707eb3f26d3b/false-error-in-xaml-parsing